# Vue.JS: Variable doesn’t update unless I open dev tools

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two buttons that show depending on a variable via a v-if tag. If the variable is false, then one button shows, if true, the other.

The bool variable is only updating when I open dev tools in chrome…I have no idea why this is.

VIDEO: https://i.gyazo.com/95a90354fdcec849cc7e33aaa5e1d8b9.mp4

Screenshot of the last frame: https://gyazo.com/ecc0cbfbc01cf6f472cea48c6cc89a4a

Button Code

```
<div class="form-row float-right">
                        <button v-if="btnDisabled" class="btn btn-success" disabled style="margin-top: 25px;">
                            Save
                        </button>
                        <button v-else class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 25px;"
                                v-on:click="createAlert()">
                            Alert me when {{desiredPriceComputed}}
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

Some of my data variables…

```
        btnDisabled: true,
        inputInvalid: false,
        hideProduct: false,
        hidePriceForm: false,
        busy: false,
```

Function for desiredPriceComputed (where the button variable to change from true to false.

```
desiredPriceComputed: function () {
            let input = this.desiredPriceInput;
            let pInput = parseFloat(this.desiredPriceInput);

            if (input == "") {
                this.inputInvalid = false;
                this.btnDisabled = true;
                this.cardAlert.desiredPrice = 0;
                return '';
            }
            if (Number.isNaN(pInput)) {
                this.inputInvalid = true;
                this.btnDisabled = true;
                this.cardAlert.desiredPrice = 0;
                return '';
            }
            if (pInput < 0) {
                this.inputInvalid = true;
                this.btnDisabled = true;
                this.cardAlert.desiredPrice = 0;
                return '';
            }
            if (pInput > 1000000000) {
                this.inputInvalid = true;
                this.btnDisabled = true;
                this.cardAlert.desiredPrice = 0;
                return '';
            }
            this.inputInvalid = false;
            this.btnDisabled = false;
            this.cardAlert.desiredPrice = pInput.toFixed(2);

            if (pInput > this.cardAlert.currentPrice) {
                return '$' + pInput.toFixed(2) + " or higher";
            }
            else if (pInput < this.cardAlert.currentPrice) {
                return '$' + pInput.toFixed(2) + " or lower";
            }
            else {
                return '$' + pInput.toFixed(2);
            }

        }
```

Some other important notes

I use Vue single file components with ASP.NET MVC razor pages.

I am currently calling Vue via the below inside the header tag.

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Mohamed Belhaj for the answer (he helped resolve in the comments of his answer).

**What went wrong**

A computed property sets the bool value to true or false.

If the computed property is not used in the template the function will never be called, that's why opening dev tools updates the variable.

**Resolution**

Update the template HTML to reference the computed property so it is called.

```
                        <div class="form-row float-right">
                            <button v-if="!desiredPriceComputed" disabled class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                                Save
                            </button>
                            <button v-else class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 25px;"
                                    v-on:click="createAlert()">
                                Alert me when {{desiredPriceComputed}}
                            </button>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an issue with the digest cycle, in desiredPriceComputed try to wrap it with this.$nextTick(() => {...}) or with a simple setTimeout(fn, 0) if it works please share more details or try to change how the button is updated (use one button instead of 2)

Comment: Just looked into $nextTick(). I haven't heard of this before. Should I wrap the entire computed variable or just the contents of the function?

Comment: `desiredPriceComputed: function () { this.$nextTick(() => ....)}`

Comment: This doesn't help. In fact, the computed property doesn't update properly at all now. https://pastebin.com/2iYVkUww

https://gyazo.com/3f2d4ee5b437913a5ee3d09dda395fea

Comment: can you restore the old version and use `<button v-if="!desiredPriceComputed" class="btn btn-success" disabled style="margin-top: 25px;">`

Comment: I just restored my previous implementation. It' similar, see below.  You seem very knowledgable in Vue. Is this a bug?

                                `<div class="form-row float-right">
                                <button :disabled="btnDisabled" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 25px;"
                                        v-on:click="createAlert()">
                                    Alert me when {{desiredPriceComputed}}
                                </button>
                            </div>`

Comment: I used vue before, looks good, with the old implementation, if the computed property is not used in the template the function will never been called, that's why when you open the dev tool it works, so I thought `<button v-if="!desiredPriceComputed" class="btn btn-success" disabled style="margin-top: 25px;">` would fix it

Comment: I just tried your implementation. It works! Thanks so much. How do I mark the comment as an answer?